# Examine for differentiability at the point multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

function $\mathcal R^m\to R$: $f(x,y) = y + \cos \sqrt[3]{x^2 + y^2}, M(0,0)$

What I found out is that, obviously,  $f'_x = \frac{-2x\sin\sqrt[3]{x^2 + y^2}}{3(x^2 + y^2)^\frac{2}{3}}$ and $f'_y =1- \frac{2y\sin\sqrt[3]{x^2 + y^2}}{3(x^2 + y^2)^\frac{2}{3}}$ in this point couldn't be calculated and the function itself is continious. But as I got it, I need to prove that both $f'_x$ and $f'_y$ continious at that point to prove differentiability. But I got stacked at this moment.

Note that function can be not differentiable at all, just couldn't prove that by myself either.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Note that by the definition we have that

- $f'_x(0,0)=0$
- $f'_y(0,0)=1$

then apply the definition to check differentiability

$$\lim_{(h,k)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{\| f(h,k)-f(0,0)-(f_x(0,0),f_y(0,0))\cdot (h,k)\|}{\| (h,k)\|}\stackrel{?}=0$$

that is

$$\lim_{(h,k)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{k + \cos \sqrt[3]{h^2 + k^2}-1-k}{\sqrt{h^2 + k^2}}\stackrel{?}=0$$

Comment: isn't it $\lim \frac {0}{0}$ ?

Comment: @МишаГлаголев That's not the key point, also $\sin x/x is 0/0$ but th elimit is $1$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: @МишаГлаголев Whoch expression do you obtain by the limit to check differentiability?

Comment: Has to be 1 as we can reduse both $f(h,k) - f(0,0)$ and $\frac{||(h,k)||}{||(h,k)||}$ to get $||-(0,1)||$, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @МишаГлаголев That part $(f_x(0,0),f_y(0,0))\cdot (h,k)$ is a dot product whic is equal to $k$, can you see that?

Comment: Oh, ok. Then the limit is $0$ as k in numerator redused, right?

Comment: @МишаГлаголев How have you evaluated the limit?

Comment: Honestly, wolfram computed that)

Comment: @МишаГлаголев Let try by hand, it you show your work in the OP up there, I will take a look to that. wolfram is useful but you need to get confident to solve that by yourself if your aimed to learn the subject.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84824/discussion-between---and-gimusi).